# how can i let a user pick a local document?

Tags: swift

I'm supposed to test PSPDFKit in a way that lets the user open a locally saved pdf file.
For this i require the files url(e.g. path, i guess). How can i let the user pick a local document?
Can anybody help me out?
I'm using storyboard and swift.

Answer (score -1):

You can present a PDF document in PSPDFKit using the `PDFViewController` like so:

```swift
// Create the `Document`.
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Document", withExtension: "pdf")!
let document = Document(url: fileURL)

// Create the PDF view controller.
let pdfController = PDFViewController(document: document)

// Present the PDF view controller within a `UINavigationController` to enable the toolbar.
present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: pdfController), animated: true)
```

For more details, take a look at the following [guide here](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/getting-started/integrating-pspdfkit/#sample-code-for-pdfviewcontroller).

Also, to present a document that your end-user has selected, consider using a document picker or a file browser. Please refer to [DocumentPickerSidebarExample.swift](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-ios-catalog/blob/master/Catalog/Examples/Top/DocumentPickerSidebarExample/DocumentPickerSidebarExample.swift) from [Catalog](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-ios-catalog) and [SwiftUI Document Browser](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-ios-swiftui-document-browser-example) for runnable example projects.

In the future, please reach out to our support portal at pspdfkit.com/support/request/ - we're happy to provide support there for our commercial SDK.

Comment: PSPDFKit is not a native framework! PDFKit - is a native framework.